# Как пересылать ботом сообщения в мой чат?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Зарегистрировал одного телеграм-бота через `@BotFather` и присылаю ему сообщения через токен бота.

Хочу, чтобы эти сообщения он пересылал в мои телеграм-чаты, этого бота я добавил в 3 моих чата и дал ему права писать.

Подскажите, в какую сторону "копать", чтобы реализовать пересылку ботом в мои 3 чата?

Answer (score 1):

Используя [документацию TelegramBotAPI](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#forwardmessage)

```
   bot.forward_message(FirstChatId, message.chat.id, message.message_id)
   bot.forward_message(SecondChatId, message.chat.id, message.message_id)
   bot.forward_message(ThirdChatId, message.chat.id, message.message_id)
```